# Which Reporting Services instance is using this ReportServer database?

Tags: ssrs

I have a SQL server - call it A - which I need to decommission.  One of the databases on it is ReportServer, so (presumably) there is somewhere a Reporting Services instance which is storing its report definitions etc in here.  Can I tell which one (we have many) just from this database?  Reporting Services is not running on server A.

I don't really want to check the config of every Reporting Services instance in the organisation one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the ReportServer database in question and run the following query it will show the SSRS web server(s) that are connected to it in the MachineName column.

```
SELECT * from Keys where Client=1
```